# Android: Activity lifecycle and Singleton

Tags: android, singleton, android-lifecycle

I'm experiencing strange behaviors and `NullPointerException` (sometimes) with a `Singleton` pattern using in an `Activity`.

The activity in manifest (declared the orientation landscape):

```
<activity
   android:name="com.lux.game.MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

The activity class:

```
private GameManager.OnEventListener mEventListener = new GameManager.OnEventListener {
   @Override
   public void onEvent(Event event) {
      if (event == Event.PLAYER_SELECTED_PUZZLE) {
         // Do something on the UI
      }
   }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // If the orientation is landscape, then initialize the Game Manager
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       GameManager.getInstance().init();

       // Register an interface to deal with game events
       GameManager.getInstance().registerForEvent(mEventListener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // The activity was destroyed, remove the interface and clear the references
    GameManager.getInstance().cleanUp();
}
```

The `GameManager` singleton:

```
public class GameManager {
   private static GameManager mInstance;

   private GameManager() {
   }

   public static synchronized getInstance() {
      if (mInstance == null) {
          mInstance = new GameManager();
      }

      return mInstance;
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `GameManager` singleton to deal with game events (player selects a card, game end, etc). The singleton is instantiated at `onCreate()` if the orientation is in landscape and an `interface` is passed to the singleton and it's stored as a member of the class. The `interface` is removed at activity's `onDestroy()`.

Activity lifecycle and logs:

```
#1 onCreate(), orientation: LANDSCAPE
#2 back button pressed
#3 onDestroy(), orientation: PORTRAIT
```

Everything was working as I expected, until I started to test the application by **locking/unlocking** and pressing the **HOME** button on the device (real device, not emulator).

Activity lifecycle and logs:

```
#1 onCreate(), orientation: LANDSCAPE
#2 lock phone
#3 onDestroy(), orientation: PORTRAIT
#4 onCreate(), orientation: PORTRAIT
#5 unlock phone
#6 onDestroy(), orientation: PORTRAIT
#7 onCreate(), orientation: LANDSCAPE
```

`onCreate` and `onDestroy` is called sever times (normal behavior because orientation change), however this does not creates an issue, because the activity's `lifecycle` methods are called in the **excpeted** order and the `interface` is removed, and I'm not leaving any reference which could cause memory leak.

The problem (sometimes) comes to the surface  if the steps above are getting called in a different order:

```
#1 onCreate(), orientation: LANDSCAPE (inst #1)
#2 lock phone
#3 onDestroy(), orientation: PORTRAIT (inst #1)
#4 onCreate(), orientation: PORTRAIT (inst #2)
#5 unlock phone
#6 onCreate(), orientation: LANDSCAPE (inst #3)
#7 onDestroy(), orientation: PORTRAIT (inst #2)
```

As you can see, step **6** and **7** are inverse compared to the previous steps. `onCreate` is called before `onDestroy`. Also I have added a number *(inst #N)*, which indicates how many activity instances are getting created and which is getting destroyed.

According to the logs, there are a total of 3 different activity instances which are getting created while I'm locking/unlocking the phone. The problem is caused by the last step, when the 3rd activity (inst #3) is created, and the 2nd activity (inst #2) is destroyed. I'm using a `Singleton` (only 1 instance exists in the whole application) to deal with events and manage the game, at activity's `onDestroy` the `Singleton` expects that the game has ended, and it must remove the references to the activity. This way, if an event occur in the game a `NullPointerException` is being thrown because the `Singleton` has cleared all the references.

1. Should I use a different approach than Singleton? (How to deal with game events?)
2. Should I use onSave/onRestore instances? (Why and how?)
3. Should I onPause/onResume instead of onCreate/onDestroy?
4. Out of ideas. If you have any good idea how to solve this issue is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should create a new class that extends Application and init your Singleton in the onCreate() metod of them.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    GameManager.getInstance().init();
    }
}
```

In your manifest, in the application tag, add **android:name="MyApplication"**
In any to have a better singleton thread safe, due to your costructor, I suggest you to create a static istance of your objet in application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static GameManager gameManager = new GameManager();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    gameManager.init();
    }
}
```

And after you can call your singleton by

```
MyApplication.gameManager
```

This is the best way to have a singleton thread safe